# Why do I not have to use "use Math::Trig" for atan2 and the like?

Tags: perl, perl-core

Why don't I have to use `use Math::Trig;` in my Perl program to call `atan2()`?

According to [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/Math::Trig#DESCRIPTION), `atan2()` is not part of the "Perl Core".

I have Perl 5.18.4.  I looked at the [list of standard Perl modules](https://perldoc.perl.org/modules#Standard-Modules), and I DO see Math::Trig listed, but I still thought that the "use" statement was required.  Admittedly, my Perl knowledge is only about 6 months old at this point.  So, a simple answer would be a quote from an official Perl document.  Or, maybe there is something else going on here that I don't understand.

Here is an example of what I am talking about.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
$value = atan2(1, 1) * 4;
print "$value\n";
```

Output:

```
  3.14159265358979
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to `use Math::Trig;` because [atan2](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/atan2) is a built-in function.  You can also see this from your command line:

```
perldoc -f atan2
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  More specifically, the link to perlfunc for built-in functions.

Answer (score 3):

Because [`atan2`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#atan2) is a builtin function, like `sin` or `cos`. Or `print`.